# How can I add an incremental class identifier to my sidebar widgets?

Tags: theme-development, widgets

My sidebar widget code in functions.php looks like this...

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Home Sidebar',
    'id' => 'home-sidebar-widget',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="menu side %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h4 class="sidebarTitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
```

Which creates this markup on the site...

```
<div class="menu side widget_text">
    <h4>widget 1 title</h4>
    <div class="textwidget">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="menu side widget_text">
    <h4>widget 2 title</h4>
    <div class="textwidget">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Here's what I need (just adding a number to the class collection)...

```
<div class="menu side s1 widget_text">
    <h4>widget 1 title</h4>
    <div class="textwidget">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="menu side s2 widget_text">
    <h4>widget 2 title</h4>
    <div class="textwidget">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

I would like to add a count variable so that each sidebar gets a number that I can then use for css targeting. How?

Comment: Keep in mind that a class name can't start with a number, so maybe something more like `<div class="menu side widget_1 widget_text">`

Comment: Good point. Not sure how I missed that one :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. However, you can try this rather hackish approach:

```
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'my_sidebar_params_cb');

function my_sidebar_params_cb($params) {
    global $my_widget_counter;
    if (empty($my_widget_counter)) $my_widget_counter = 1;
    else $my_widget_counter++;
    $params[0]['before_widget'] = str_replace('class="', 'class="widget_nr_'.$my_widget_counter.' ', $params[0]['before_widget']);
    return $params;
}
```

Comment: +1 - Might be hackish, but if it works this would be my preferred method.

Comment: @Scott B: One more thing...if you have a chance to do this within your own class, i'd strongly recommend that, as you can then store the counter as `$this->widget_counter` rather than dumping it into the global scope (which is what i don't like about this solution).

Comment: Just wanted to add ( this came up in search) that using something like this to hard-code widget styles will break styles if you drag widgets around or add any new widgets.

Answer (score 2):

You could target specific elements in CSS like so..(won't work for all browsers of course).

```
#sidebar div.menu.side:nth-child(1) { /* First */ }
#sidebar div.menu.side:nth-child(2) { /* Second */ }
#sidebar div.menu.side:nth-child(3) { /* Third */ }

..and so on...
```

Or use some jQuery to add the classes..

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var wi = 1;
    $('#sidebar div.menu.side').each( function() {
        $(this).addClass( 'widget-s' + wi );
        wi = wi + 1;
    });
});
```

wyrfel's approach looks like it could work for you though, i'd suggest that over the two above.

Comment: You're getting +1 from me, too...mostly for thinking around the square. ;-)