# allow user to style widget backgound per widget

Tags: widgets

Is there a way to allow a user to style a widgets backgound per widget?
Lets say there are 4 widgets in the sidebar, i want the user to be able to style the first 2 with a blue background, the second with a purple background and the final one to have no background but how would you allow the user to make this choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default theme, or if you have one that is properly written, each widget has a unique CSS class name, you can simply add it to your style sheet.

If it does not, and you want to add a unique CSS class based on the widget placement, as in the order you have drag + dropped it into your sidebar, this was answered here: [How can I add an incremental class identifier to my sidebar widgets?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11145/how-can-i-add-an-incremental-class-identifier-to-my-sidebar-widgets/11148#11148)

The code in wyrfel's answer will work in your case, but remember that the *unique CSS is based on the widget placement in your admin* **and any removal or moving of them will effect how your CSS is applied.**

The alternative is to add a static unique CSS name based on the widget ID, so it doesnt matter where it is placed, the following function should do that,

```
add_filter('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'sidebar_widget_styling_sws');
function sidebar_widget_styling_sws($params){
  $params[0]['before_widget'] = '<div class="widget-'.@$params[0]['widget_id'].'">';
  return $params;
}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks for the links they helped a lot :)